# What is const { }

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading [an article](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable) right now that contains following statement:

```
const { items } = this.state;
```

My level of Javascript knowledge is not so high. I can not understand command **const {}**. Also, I could not find some guidelines regard it. What is a constant object create this command?

Comment: This is called "destructuring".

Comment: Check [this](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment)